# Unable to load class 'com.hazelcast.instance.Node$2' in Karaf Cellar

Tags: java, hazelcast, karaf

I discovered an issue in using Karaf 4.1.5 and Karaf Cellar 4.1.2 for
make cluster that contained 10 server with IPv4 connection. at first
step karaf installed and karaf cellar too then hazelcast.xml file edited
for configure IP interface on network. when  install finished on all
servers, I found all IPs on cluster nodes list but when one of nodes
restarted (stop then start), hazelcast crash and cluster:* command on
all servers not recognized. I found exception on karaf.log file about
hazelcast and TCP/IP connection exception error. this experience
repeated again and again. I want to use Karaf Cellar technology in
critical project than every crash could cause big problems! please guide
me for using of Cellar or inform me if Karaf Cellar is not reliable .

Hazelcast Configuration file edited as follow:

```
<join>
        <multicast enabled="false">
            <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
            <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
        </multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <interface>10.12.47.125</interface>
            <interface>10.12.47.126</interface>
            <interface>10.12.47.127</interface>
            <interface>10.12.47.128</interface>
            <interface>10.12.47.129</interface>
            <interface>10.12.47.130</interface>
            <interface>10.12.47.131</interface>
            <interface>10.12.47.132</interface>
            <interface>10.12.47.133</interface>
            <interface>10.12.47.134</interface>
        </tcp-ip>
        <aws enabled="false">
            <access-key>my-access-key</access-key>
            <secret-key>my-secret-key</secret-key>
            <!--optional, default is us-east-1 -->
            <region>us-west-1</region>
            <!--optional, default is ec2.amazonaws.com. If set, region shouldn't be set as it will override this property -->
            <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
            <!-- optional, only instances belonging to this group will be discovered, default will try all running instances -->
            <security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name>
            <tag-key>type</tag-key>
            <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
        </aws>
    </join>
```

Comment: Can you share some logs to better understand the issue?

Comment: Karaf.log file contained exception error, you can access it on this link : [link](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IO9X7) thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

karaf cellar 4.1.2 is not compatible with karaf 4.1.5. solution of this issue is updating karaf to 4.2.1 or higher.